# Empty layout inspector on Mac M1 chip

Tags: android-studio

The layout inspector is not showing anything, even though I have my app running on my device. Does anyone know what I can do here? I am running a Mac Mini with M1 chip.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio IDE with layout inspector tab open and active]

Comment: Same here. I'm using a Macbook pro M1.

Comment: Manually launching it by ```./Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer``` got an exception.   

```SWT folder '/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/aarch64' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.```

There are only x86 and x86_64 in the folder, I think it does not support ARM64 with OSX now.